# Учитывать вложенные файлы в папки

Tags: delphi

Есть программа, которая ищет файлы в папке и вносит изменения в них, но она не учитывает вложенные папки.

Что тут прописать, чтобы она учитывала вложенные папки ?:
Код:

```
procedure Tfrm_Main.cb_SubfolderClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin

end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из вашего кода, что вы привели, ничего не понятно. Пустая процедура и всё :) Ладно, вопрос примерно ясен.

Всё зависит от того, КАК вы ищете файлы по заданному пути. Если вы это делаете с помощью FindFirst, то используйте, например, рекурсию, проверяя, папка ли это или файл:

```
procedure FindAllAdnChange(path:string);
var
   sr: TSearchRec;
   s:string;
begin
   s:=path+'\*.*'; // будем искать все объекты в текущей папке
   if FindFirst(s, faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then // нашли что-то
     repeat
      if ((sr.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0) and (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') then // если это папка, причём не "." и не ".."
           FindAllAdnChange(path+'\'+sr.Name) // запустим рекурсию, перейдя на уровень ниже
      else // а если это файл
         begin
           // тут делаем, что мы хотим с нашими файлами
         end;
     until FindNext(sr) <> 0; // пока не кончится цепочка найденных объектов в папке
   FindClose(sr); // освобождаем ресурсы
end;
```

Вызываем процедуру так:

```
FindAllAdnChange('K:\Utils');
```

По-хорошему, нужно ещё бы проверять в процедуре уровень рекурсии, просто увеличивая счётчик. Но это вы уже сами :)

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, зачем в процедуре проверять уровень рекурсии?

Comment: @Kromster во-первых, очень большой уровень вложенности рекурсии может вызвать переполнение стека (маловероятно для дерева каталогов, тем более, что FindFirst/FindNext не обнаруживают циклические симлинки, но на всякий случай стоит), во-вторых, просто глубина вложенности может понадобиться для чего-то: статистика, сохранение параметров, в третьих,  может понадобиться ограничить процедуру глубиной работы

Comment: "может вызвать", но для дерева каталогов это излишне. "может понадобиться для чего-то" не аргумент, под ним можно вообще все что угодно в код включить.

Comment: Ну, почему же, если собираешься это дерево отрисовывать, то далеко не лишне знать, на какой стадии рекурсии ты находишься.

Comment: а если не собираешься отрисовывать? ;-) )))

Comment: @Kromster Тогда, как у блондинки и динозавра :)  К тому же не совсем понятно, похоже, что на виртуальных дисках циклические симлинки всё-таки могут быть найдены FindFirst/FindNext и тогда контроль уровня рекурсии всё же может быть полезен по умолчанию, хотя бы как простейшая защита.