# Как обрабатывать все файлы в папке и подпапках в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, файлы

**ЗАДАНИЕ:** Данный код обрабатывает только один файл. Как добавить возможность обрабатывать не один файл, а все файлы что находятся в папке и подпапках?

```
var
    SynArr: Array of Array of String;
      VocFile,SrcFile,DstFile: TextFile;
      TxtLine: String;
      SynList: TStringList;
    begin
     AssignFile(VocFile, OpenDialog2.FileName);
     Reset(VocFile);
     SetLength(SynArr, 0);
     SynList := TStringList.Create;
     while not Eof(VocFile)
     do begin
        ReadLn(VocFile, TxtLine);
        SynList.Text := StringReplace(WrapText(TxtLine,#13#10,['|'],1),'|','',[rfReplaceAll]);
        SetLength(SynArr, Length(SynArr)+1);
        SetLength(SynArr[High(SynArr)],SynList.Count);
        for i := 0 to SynList.Count - 1
        do SynArr[High(SynArr),i] := SynList.Strings[i];
        end;
     SynList.Free;
     CloseFile(VocFile);

     AssignFile(SrcFile, OpenDialog3.FileName);
     Reset(SrcFile);

     AssignFile(DstFile, OpenDialog4.FileName);
     Rewrite(DstFile);
     while not Eof(SrcFile)
     do begin
        ReadLn(SrcFile, TxtLine);
        for i := 0 to High(SynArr)
        do for j := 0 to High(SynArr[i])
           do TxtLine := StringReplace(TxtLine,SynArr[i,j],SynArr[i,Random(High(SynArr[i]))+1],[]);
        WriteLn(DstFile, TxtLine);
        end;
     CloseFile(DstFile);
     CloseFile(Srcfile);
    end;
```

Отличие этого вопроса от предыдущего в том что: Тут приведен другой код - именно в котором не получается добавить обработку всех файлов.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Учитывать вложенные файлы в папки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779813/%d0%a3%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Если есть возможность, поможете в решении этого вопроса ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно получить список файлов, что можно сделать при помощи `TDirectory` из `System.IOUtils`:

```
var files: TStringDynArray; //тип TStringDynArray объявлен в System.Types

files := TDirectory.GetFiles(root, '*.*', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
```

где `root` - путь папки. Затем в цикле выполнить обработку каждого файла:

```
for i := 0 to Length(files) - 1 do
begin
  // здесь нужные действия для files[i]
end;
```

В старых версиях Delphi (например Delphi 7) придётся написать собственную подпрограмму для получения списка файлов. Например такую:

```
procedure GetFiles(const dir: string; list: TStrings);
var rec: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(dir + '\*.*', faAnyFile, rec) = 0 then
  repeat
    if (rec.Name = '.') or (rec.Name = '..') then Continue;
    if (rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then GetFiles(dir + '\' + rec.Name, list)
    else list.Add(dir + '\' + rec.Name);
  until FindNext(rec) <> 0;
  FindClose(rec);
end;
```

Код обработки тогда будет таким:

```
var files: TStringList;

files := TStringList.Create;
GetFiles(root, files);
for i := 0 to files.Count - 1 do
begin
  // здесь нужные действия для files[i] 
end;
files.Free;
```